# Hide action's buttons in contact details when I use CNContactPicker

Tags: ios, objective-c, cncontactviewcontroller, cncontactpicker

I use `CNContactPickerViewController` and I want to hide actions buttons (call, message, facetime) from contact's detail.

I know about `allowActions` property in `CNContactViewController`, but I don't know, how I can get access to this property, if I use `CNContacPickerViewController`.

How I can hide actions buttons from contact's detail when using `CNContactPickerViewController`?

Comment: Did you get the solution for this? I have the same requirement for my Application.

Comment: Yes, I wrote my own ContactViewController))

Comment: FYI: `allowActions` doesn't control the circular buttons you've described.

Comment: @Artem - any chance you'd be willing to self-answer by posting your custom `ContactViewController`?

Answer (score 0):

You can't use `allowActions` property with `CNContactPickerViewController`. I am using this approach and its not showing details of any contact, it only shows list like this [image]

After that you can select any contact and delegate method will give you contact details of that contact.

```
-(void) openDeviceContactList {
    CNContactPickerViewController *contactPicker = [CNContactPickerViewController new];
    contactPicker.delegate = self;
    [self presentViewController:contactPicker animated:YES completion:nil];
}

- (void) contactPicker:(CNContactPickerViewController *)picker didSelectContact:(CNContact *)contact {
    [self getPhoneNumberFrom:contact];
}

-(void)getPhoneNumberFrom:(CNContact *)contactObject {

    NSString * phone = @"";
    NSString * userPHONE_NO = @"";
    for(CNLabeledValue * phonelabel in contactObject.phoneNumbers) {
        CNPhoneNumber * phoneNo = phonelabel.value;
        phone = [phoneNo stringValue];
        if (phone) {
            userPHONE_NO = phone;
        }
        break;
    }
    NSLog(@"PHONE NO :: %@",userPHONE_NO);
}
```

Call `[self openDeviceContactList];` on button tap from which you want to open contact list. This will present `CNContactPickerViewController`. For this cause you have to implement `CNContactPickerDelegate` and also you have to add `ContactsUI.framework` and `Contacts.framework`from `Build Settings`.

This is working code.

IMP NOTE: This will work iOS 9.0 onwards only. If you are supporting 8.0 onwards then add OS check and use AddressBook.framework & AddressBookUI.framework

Comment: CNContactPickerViewController doesn't have an allowActions property.

Comment: @ArtemUpdated answer, please check. And its working solution from y current project.

Comment: No, I need to show contact details and I want to hide actions button.
http://www.howtogeek.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/09/pcm_top.png it is example which buttons I want to hide.

Maybe I need to show CNContactViewController in didSelectContact delegate?